# ¿Cuál es el efecto de no poner comillas en un echo?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Entiendo cómo funciona poner comillas:

- Cuando son dobles interpreta todo lo que tenga `$`  `` ` ``  y `\`.
- Cuando son simples pone todo literalmente.

Pero, ¿qué hace exactamente no poner comillas? ¿Es lo mismo que las dobles comillas pero sustituyendo grandes espacios y tabuladores por un solo espacio? Es lo que parece a simple vista.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

¡Muy buena pregunta! Además de lo que comentas, pueden pasar muchas cosas:

#### Se realiza la expansión de parámetros al interpretarse todo como `glob`

Dado un directorio `/tmp/dir` con tres ficheros `a1`, `a2` y `c1`, si escribimos `*` fuera de comillas nos expandirá a todo este contenido:

```
$ echo *
a1 a2 c1
```

Sin embargo, si le ponemos comillas escribirá literalmente `*`:

```
$ echo "*"
*
```

Lo mismo si utilizamos algún parámetro:

```
$ echo a*
a1 a2
$ echo "a*"
a*
```

O

```
$ echo [a-c][0-1]
a1 c1
$ echo "[a-c][0-1]"
[a-c][0-1]
```

Y un largo etcétera de ejemplos.

#### El resultado se separa en `IFS` y se "traga" los demás si hay múltiples

Supongamos que definimos una cadena de tres líneas:

```
"hola            como estas     yo    # <--- hay espacios tras "yo"
muy
bien         "
```

Así:

```
$ v="hola            como estas     yo    
... muy
... bien         "
```

Cuando realizamos `echo` con comillas, todo esto se mantiene:

```
$ echo "$v"
hola            como estas     yo    # <--- los espacios finales están presentes
muy
bien
```

Sin embargo al quitar las comillas todos los múltiples espacios, tabuladores y saltos de línea se convierten en un único espacio:

```
$ echo $v
hola como estas yo muy bien
```

---

Más informaciones <sub>en inglés</sub>.

- [When is double-quoting necessary?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/68748/40596)
- [Quotes and escaping](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/quoting)