# ¿Cómo conservo el formato de una salida de un comando al imprimirlo?

Tags: bash

Quiero imprimir los metadadatos de un fichero por pantalla, para ello uso el comando `Exiftools` directamente en el terminal y me sale lo siguiente:

```
ExifTool Version Number         : 10.80

File Name                       : LoremIpsum-1e40fa12a5e7ce47ebcaaace81f6fd06.pdf

Directory                       : .

File Size                       : 30 kB

File Modification Date/Time     : 2018:11:20 12:49:48+01:00

File Access Date/Time           : 2018:11:20 12:49:51+01:00
```

Y así sucesivamente...

Luego intento hacer lo mismo pero con un script. Me printa la misma salida de todo en una línea, de esta forma:

```
ExifTool Version Number : 10.80 File Name : LoremIpsum-1e40fa12a5e7ce47ebcaaace81f6fd06.pdf Directory : /home/ File Size : 30 kB File Modification Date/Time : 2018:11:20 12:14:50+01:00 File Access Date/Time : 2018:11:20 12:14:50+01:00 File Inode Change Date/Time : 2018:11:20 12:14:50+01:00 File Permissions : rw-r--r-- File Type : PDF File Type Extension : pdf MIME Type : application/pdf PDF Version : 1.4 Linearized : No Page Count : 1 XMP Toolkit : Image::ExifTool 10.55 Creator : John Doe Language : none Author : Aldus Corporation Producer : Metadata is dangerous! Create Date : 2017:11:09 13:06:08+01:00
```

Yo lo que quiero es que la salida me salga como arriba cuando ejecuto el comando directamente por el terminal, pero no hay manera.

El codigo del script es el siguiente:

```
echo $(exiftool  $1)
```

Answer (score 2):

Esto es porque `echo` de un contenido sin comillas dobles no conserva el formato:

```
$ v="   hola
que tal"
$ echo $v          # formato perdido
hola que tal
$ echo "$v"        # formato conservado
   hola
que tal
```

Por tanto, debes utilizar:

```
echo "$(exiftool  "$1")"
#    ^               ^
```

O, como bien explica nxnev en los comentarios, omitir `echo` directamente y escribir:

```
exiftool "$1"
```

Puedes ver otros casos parecidos en [¿Cuál es el efecto de no poner comillas en un echo?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/96179/83)

Comment: Buena respuesta. Como nota adicional, `echo` es redundante en este caso y `$1` también debería estar entre comillas (para prevenir el _field splitting_ en la ruta del archivo).

Comment: @nxnev bien visto! Editado con lo que comentas