# ¿Cómo guardo el resultado de un comando en una variable de Bash?

Tags: linux, bash

¿Es posible guardar el resultado de una acumulación que se hace en una variable dentro de awk en una variable del script de bash que estoy haciendo?

He buscado por internet y solo encuentro lo inverso, usar una variable del script dentro de Awk.

Comment: Ayer no encontré posible duplicado, pero sabía que en algún lugar lo había.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sí, solamente debes hacer `variable=$(comando)`, lo que se llama la *sustitución de comando*. El resultado que emite el comando se guarda en `$variable`.

En el caso particular de Awk, lo tienes que devolver usando `print` o similares.

Por ejemplo si tenemos:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{print 1}'
1
```

Entonces:

```
$ res=$(awk 'BEGIN{print 1}')
$ echo "$res"
1
```

---

A la hora de utilizar la variable, es bueno que tengas en cuenta lo descrito en [¿Cuál es el efecto de no poner comillas en un echo?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/96303/83) y usar comillas dobles.
Ejemplo:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{print 1; print 2}'
1
2
$ res=$(awk 'BEGIN{print 1; print 2}')
$ echo $res
1 2              # Sin comillas se pierden los saltos de línea
$ echo "$res"
1
2                # Con comillas se conservan
```