# Reemplazo de contenido de un archivo con un char pasado por parámetro

Tags: linux, bash, script

es mi primer post. Actualmente me estoy iniciando en Scripting en Bash. Mi duda recae en el siguiente enunciado:
"Reemplazar todos los dígitos por un caracter dado como parámetro".

El reemplazo se que puedo hacerlo de esta manera:
`sed -i 's/[0-9]/CHARACTER/g' file`

Sin dudas al ponerle cualquier String lo hace correctamente. Ahora interpreto que el caracter como parámetro debe ingresarlo el usuario. Y lo hago de esta forma:
read input

Sin embargo, cuando quiero asifnar al "path" esa variable String me reemplaza por el literal. Probé estas formas y así es el output:

```
sed -i 's/[0-9]/$input/g' file
sed -i 's/[0-9]/${input}/g' file
sed -i 's/[0-9]/"$input"/g' file
sed -i 's/[0-9]/$(input)/g' file
```

Y todas reemplazas por esas ocurrencias. Mi pregunta recae en cómo tomar el valor del String en ese path para qué lo reconozca.
Muchas gracias!

---

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Please insert a char" 
read input 
sed -i "s/[0-9]/$input/g" archivo1 
cat archivo1
```

No me modifica el archivo. Otra de las cosas que hice para ver si funcionaba fue esto:
Desde la terminal : `sh prueba.sh archivo1 &`
En el script:

```
#!/bin/bash
    
sed -i "s/[0-9]/$2/g" $1 
cat archivo1
```

Y esto ya directamente no me funciona.

Answer (score 1):

**Respuesta rápida**: usa **comillas dobles** en el script en lugar de simples:

```
$ input=NUEVA; sed "s/[0-9]/$input/g" <<< "a1b2c3"
aNUEVAbNUEVAcNUEVA
```

### Otras aclaraciones

1. No sé a que te refieres con "asignar al path", aunque tengo la sospecha de que crees que esto `///`, es un "path". En ese caso, no es así.

La implementación de `sed` permite el comando de tipo `s/<patron>/<reemplazo>/` para reemplazar lo que se encuentre, pero también los caracteres `/` son por conveniencia; puedes utilizar otros (pero sólo uno), por ejemplo:

```
$ sed 's@<patron>@<reemplazo>' archivo
```

Incluso algunos más bizarros, como letras cualquiera:

```
$ sed 'sT<patron>T<reemplazo>' archivo
```

Ya depende del uso que le quieras dar.

2. Tu problema que no es con `sed`, es con la **expansión** y **sustitución** de la variable `$input`.

En Bash (y otras shells), el contenido de una variable se expande con el signo de `$` precediéndola, pero cuando la encierras con caracteres como comillas simples `'`, o comillas dobles `"`, cambia el resultado. Sin comillas, se expande sin (muchos) problemas.

Esto es porque el entrecomillado es un **mecanismo especial** —y no un lujo o mero capricho— de las shell's.

El propósito del entrecomillado (como en el lenguaje mismo que escribes), es cambiar el uso de lo que se encuentre en medio. Citando de `bash(1)`, de la sección `QUOTING`:

> Quoting is used to remove the special meaning of certain characters or words to the
> shell.  Quoting can be used to disable special treatment for  special  characters,  to
> prevent reserved words from being recognized as such, and to prevent parameter
> expansion.

#### Comillas dobles

Lo que se encierre dentro de estas comillas será tomado literalmente salvo los caracteres $, , `, y !

Por eso es que mi respuesta es que uses comillas dobles, porque estas, al permitir que $input expanda el valor de esta variable, pueden poner su contenido dentro del script de `sed`.

#### Comillas simples

**Todo** lo que se encierre dentro de estas comillas será tomado literalmente.

Por esto es que, en tu ejemplo, no se sustituía la variable `$input`, puesto que era tomada literalmente como la cadena "$input".

No importa si dentro de estas comillas simples (las que estén más a los extremos) pongas otras comillas dobles, los caracteres $, &lt, (, ". Todo será tomado literal, sin expansiones, sin sustituciones, sin tratos especiales.

En el siguiente enlace puedes encontrar un tema relacionado sobre el entrecomillado:

- [¿Cuál es el efecto de no poner comillas en un echo?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/96179/cu%C3%A1l-es-el-efecto-de-no-poner-comillas-en-un-echo)

Comment: Probé lo siguiente:

#!/bin/bash
echo "Please insert a char"
read input
sed -i "s/[0-9]/$input/g" archivo1
cat archivo1

Y sigue sin funcionarme. De hecho ahora ni siquiera me reemplaza.

Comment: No puedo entender el código de tu comentario. Te sugiero que lo añadas a tu publicación.